# customizing openstack swfit middleware

Tags: cloud, middleware, openstack, openstack-swift

I want to write openstack/swift middleware. but I don't know where to put my code after development so that I can put it on the pipeline later.
According to it's [document](https://docs.openstack.org/operations-guide/ops-customize-objectstorage.html) I have to put it on /opt/stack/swift. but I didn't install openstack-swift via "devstack" so I don't have that path.

what should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood we have yo put our middleware code in this path in the proxy node:

**/usr/lib/python3/site-packages/swift/common/middleware/MIDDLEWARE_NAME.py**

then configuring the /etc/swift/proxy-server.conf

```
[filter:ip_whitelist]
paste.filter_factory = swift.common.middleware.ip_whitelist:filter_factory
# You can override the default log routing for this filter here:
# set log_name = ratelimit
# set log_facility = LOG_LOCAL0
# set log_level = INFO
# set log_headers = False
# set log_address = /dev/log
deny_message = You shall not pass!
```

you can see more on this [link](https://docs.openstack.org/operations-guide/ops-customize-objectstorage.html).